# Passing same object several times to different methods Java

Tags: java, optimization, boolean

I need to check if the object entity satisfies certain rules. My object is a phone call, I need to check if it satisfies certain criteria or not to proceed with later logic. Please, find my solution below.

```
 private static boolean isGPRS(CallXCD callXCD){

   String serviceName = callXCD.getServiceName();
   boolean isGPRS = false;

   if(serviceName.compareTo("GPRSB")==0)
     isGPRS = true;

   return isGPRS;
}

private static boolean isVoice(CallXCD callXCD){

  String serviceName = callXCD.getServiceName();
  boolean isVoice = false;

  if(serviceName.compareTo("TEL")==0)
      isVoice = true;

  return isVoice;
}
```

Then I will check if isGPRS returns true, I will do X. If isVoice returns true, I will do Y. I am not sure if what I did was the best practice because I pass the same object several times.

Is it better to build an array of booleans and pass the object one time in one method, do all calculations then pass the values to the boolean array. Or wouldn't it make any difference on performance?

Comment: This should be at Code Review. If you post to CR, please add additional information, f.e. what CallXCD is and how it is structured.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code.

Comment: You could use an **enum** to store the different "types" this object can represent. I think it is much more readable than a boolean array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of this will make any measurable difference.  Such trivial things won't affect performance in a way that you'll be able to tell.

I'd wonder why you have to do this at all.  Why static methods?  Why not make those members of the `CallXCD` class and let it simply tell you what kind of thing it is?  Keep all the state and logic encapsulated in one place.

Why are you testing types this way?  Could this be polymorphic?  Object-oriented programming was born to eliminate this kind of "what am I?" if/then/else code.

Comment: Thank you duffymo. I will try your suggested practice. It seems much much better